# WP7 - Error 'XmlException was unhandled' despite checking if the file exists

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing, windows-phone

I'm attempting to read from an XML document in WP7 and have run into a weird error that I simply just don't get, when I run my program from the first time after restarting the WP7 emulator but if I run it in debug without closing the emulator it gives me the runtime error: 'XmlException was unhandled Cannot find file 'appdata.xml' in the application xap package.' which is strange because I check to see if the file exists first:

```
using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    if (store.FileExists("appdata.xml"))
    {
        XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load("appdata.xml"); // <-- runtime error
        //code for parsing xml to variables
    }
}
```

It enters the if statement so the file should exist but XDocument doesn't like it for some reason, anyone have any ideas?

For further reference here is how I am saving my data when I tap a button in an app, also **the error does not occur if this function isn't called**:

```
private void SaveData()
{
    rulesData = new AppData(StartCashRule.Text, LandGoRule.Text, FreeParkingRule.Text, FullCircuitRule.Text, AuctionRule.Text);

    using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        IsolatedStorageFileStream ifStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("appdata.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, store);

        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ifStream))
        {
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("myData");

            writer.WriteElementString("Starting_Cash", rulesData.myStartingCash);
            writer.WriteElementString("Land_on_Go_Data", rulesData.myLandOnGo);
            writer.WriteElementString("Free_Parking_Data", rulesData.myFreeParking);
            writer.WriteElementString("Full_Circuit_Data", rulesData.myFullCircuit);
            writer.WriteElementString("Auction_Data", rulesData.myAuction);

            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
        }

        ifStream.Close();
    }
}
```

Thanks - Ryan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing to XDocument.Load the name "appdata.xml" without any reference to the IsolatedStorage store where the file really exists.

You should write something like this

```
XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load(store.OpenFile("appdata.xml", FileMode.Open));
```

Comment: Thanks :) although I now get the error when I open the file as an IsolatedStorageFileStream in my save function, how do I close the file after I read it as I don't see a store.close() or loadedData.close() function? Thanks

Comment: In which line do you get the exception and what exception?

Comment: Since I closed and reopened the project I'm getting a new error: XDocument loadedData = Document.Load(store.OpenFile("appdata.xml",FileMode.Open)); in the ReadData function, the exception is XmlException "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 422."

Comment: Usually this means that the xml file is not valid xml. Can you confirm that the XML is well formed? Try to open the XML file using IE and check if there are errors.

Comment: IsolatedStorageFileStream ifStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("appdata.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, store); gives me the error "Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream.", my guess is that I need to close the xml file after reading from it but I don't see any closing functions for XDocument, any ideas?